# Renaming documents in a directory with powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi Im trying to rename multiples files using powershell. 
Currently I am using

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf -recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '04282020', '' }
```

Some example files names are:

```
4/30/2020  2:43 PM    101268 04062020MACNN@CN.comNaveLoad 3206078552020-6.pdf
4/30/2020  2:41 PM    Load 3202895372020-04-06T22 00 03+00 00doc882532627.pdf
4/30/2020  3:50 PM    0407202 Load 3206618002020-04-07T14 04 07+00 00doc882732300.pdf
```

I want to rename documents to have the following format:

```
Load 320607855
Load 320289537
Load 320661800
etc.....
```

Most files have the order numbers and customers in the name. How can I removed all the other unwanted text

Comment: Are the numbers you seek alway 9 digits long?

Comment: No they are not. They can vary.

Comment: Then this is really confusing.. Your example file names _cannot_ be filenames because of the timestamps where you have both slashes and colon characters that aren't allowed in a file name. What exactly is that you're showing? An email subject line perhaps? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61532856/edit) your question and show us the actual filenames as they show up in Explorer.

Comment: They can vary. I have microsoft flow download and rename documents with email subject and sender with time stamps. For the most part most customers include order number in the subject.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in another comment, but that doesn't make it any clearer. Why do you not show the filenames as they are right now and how they should be after renaming? This way, it's a guessing game.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the document names. I was previously printing all documents, and had files automatically printed and time stamped. Microsoft flow also added in an extra time stamp there also. I can get some of the stamps removed, but still need to remove the extra text that comes from email subjects.

Comment: 04292020rkinnairdspotinc.comRE  CAN YOU DO THESE 202029T20 53 58+00 00S308267-RateConfirmation.pdf"
Load 322352644 10+00889320426.pdf"
Load Confirmation - Load 321902202202030T12 09 22+00 00doc889563941.pdf"

Comment: 04292020rkinnairdspotinc.comRE CAN YOU DO THESE 202029T20 53 58+00 00S308267-RateConfirmation.pdf"            this for example I would like to rename.   Load S308267                            Load 322352644 10+00889320426.pdf"    this Load 322352644.    etc...   I did post some up in the original post. Again sorry for some of the confusion or lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This screams out for Regular Expressions! this is also where you can use some cool capture groups:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem *.pdf -recurse
$Files | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.*(Load \d{9}).*(\..*)$','$1$2' }
```

The Regex:

```
.*(Load \d{9}).*(\..*)$

.* - Match 0 or more of any character
(  - Start of Capture Group 1 the "Load 123456789"
  Load  - Match "Load "
  \d{9} - Match exactly 9 Digits
)  - End Capture Group 1
.* - Match 0 or more of any character
(  - Start of Capture Group 2 the file extension ".pdf"
  \.    - Match a dot
  .*    - Match 0 or more of any character
)  - End Capture Group 2
$  - End. Make sure that you only match the extension at the end of the string
```

Then for the replacement:

```
$1$2

$1 - Replace with the first capture group e.g. "Load 123456789"
$2 - Replace with the second capture group e.g. ".pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not been super clear about how you can identify an order number vs the other numbers in the names. Assuming your order numbers always follow the string "Load " and are always 9 digits long:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf -recurse | Foreach {
    Rename-Item -NewName ([regex]::matches($_.Name, 'Load \d{9}').value + $_.Extension) -Path $_.Fullname -WhatIf
}
```

would do it. Note: because we're selecting a certain string out of the full name we must add the extension back to the rename, otherwise it would be stripped of the new filename. Test first with -WhatIf, and remove when you're happy with the result.

Comment: Hey sorry about those missing details. But I use a Microsoft flow to download the order documents from incoming emails. We get the pdfs downloaded to have date stamp and email subject. Most email subjects include the order numbers.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, where you have put new examples (BTW, you should have edited your question and added these there), I gather you need two different regex tests.

One is for filenames that include the word `Load` and the other where that is not the case, but instead contains a string like `00S308267-RateConfirmation`.

Seems quite messy to me, but can be done, for instance like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.pdf' -File -Recurse | 
Rename-Item -NewName {
    switch -Regex ($_.BaseName) {
        'Load\s*\d+'               { '{0}.pdf' -f ($_ -replace '.*(Load\s*\d+)2020-.*', '$1') ; break}
        '\d+S\d+-RateConfirmation' { 'Load {0}.pdf' -f ($_ -replace '.*(S\d+).*', '$1') ; break}
    }
}
```

Before:

```
D:\TEST
    0407202 Load 3206618002020-04-07T14 04 07+00 00doc882732300.pdf
    04292020rkinnairdspotinc.comRE CAN YOU DO THESE 202029T20 53 58+00 00S308267-RateConfirmation.pdf
    101268 04062020MACNN@CN.comNaveLoad 3206078552020-6.pdf
    Load 3202895372020-04-06T22 00 03+00 00doc882532627.pdf
```

After:

```
D:\TEST
    Load 320289537.pdf
    Load 320607855.pdf
    Load 320661800.pdf
    Load S308267.pdf
```